# AWSの逆引きDNS申請でrtpレコードの設定が上手くいかないためか、申請が通りません。

Tags: aws, dns

現在、メール送信において、スパム判定されてしまっております。

調べてていると
AWSを使用しており、Elastic IPの制限解除の申請をしなくてはいけないとのことでしたので
次のURL等を参照し、申請を送ってみました。

http://toatoshi.hatenablog.com/entry/2013/07/04/091846

現在使用しているElasticIPと、Aレコードとして設定しているドメイン  hoge.example.com(仮) を提出しました。

しかし、次のように返答がきております。

> The mapping for this reverse DNS entry is failing because the PTR record doesn't match the A record for that domain. We currently require the forward A record to match the PTR record for all reverse DNS entries.
>
> You can either provide us with an alternate hostname, or configure the A　record for this domain to match the desired PTR record on your side.

PTRレコードについての知識に乏しく調べつつ、必要な情報を添付の上、再提出したいのですが、
何を提供したら申請が通るのかがわかりません。

こういうケースにおける、対応の仕方を教えて頂けますと幸いです。

宜しくお願い致します。

現状は参照し、Route53にptrレコードを追加しております。
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=115473

$ nslookup -type=ptr [IPアドレス]

を実行しているのですが、現時点では、特に変化がありませんでした。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/83343

Answer (score 0):

AWSの手続きには詳しくないのですが、PTRレコードの設定はこの申請に従ってAmazonが行うところ、申請内容がおかしいのでリジェクトされた、という話ではないでしょうか。

別のホスト名を提出するか、希望のPTRレコードに一致するようAレコードを設定しろ、と書かれています。

hoge.example.comのAレコードが申請したとおりのIPアドレスを返すよう設定されていないのでは。

Answer (score 0):

逆引き申請の前に、`A` レコード(正引き) の登録が必用です。

`example.com` ゾーンに ホスト名＝`hoge.example.com`、タイプ＝`A`、値＝`Elastic ipのアドレス` を登録してください。